# Re-upload: Can someone check the addresssanitizer result?

Tags: linux, malloc, fuzzing

I ran AFL fuzzer to open source program and I ran the program with the output crash from the fuzzing.

This is the result of address sanitizer but I am not sure what this error actually is.

```
ubuntu@ifn657:~/fuzz3/dact-0.8.42$ ./dact -dcf output/crashes/id:000023,sig:06,src:000013,time:312754,op:flip1,pos:20
=================================================================
==4163826==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: heap-buffer-overflow on address 0x7f321f8fe80b at pc 0x000000495900 bp 0x7ffebce27520 sp 0x7ffebce26ce8
WRITE of size 747621 at 0x7f321f8fe80b thread T0
    #0 0x4958ff in __asan_memcpy (/home/ubuntu/fuzz3/dact-0.8.42/dact+0x4958ff)
    #1 0x4ce218 in comp_plain_algo /home/ubuntu/fuzz3/dact-0.8.42/comp_plain.c
    #2 0x4cc623 in dact_blk_decompress /home/ubuntu/fuzz3/dact-0.8.42/dact_common.c:176:9
    #3 0x4cc623 in dact_process_file /home/ubuntu/fuzz3/dact-0.8.42/dact_common.c:658:20
    #4 0x4d4fc1 in main /home/ubuntu/fuzz3/dact-0.8.42/dact.c:689:8
    #5 0x7f322262a0b2 in __libc_start_main /build/glibc-YYA7BZ/glibc-2.31/csu/../csu/libc-start.c:308:16
    #6 0x41e50d in _start (/home/ubuntu/fuzz3/dact-0.8.42/dact+0x41e50d)

0x7f321f8fe80b is located 0 bytes to the right of 524299-byte region [0x7f321f87e800,0x7f321f8fe80b)
allocated by thread T0 here:
    #0 0x49640d in malloc (/home/ubuntu/fuzz3/dact-0.8.42/dact+0x49640d)
    #1 0x4cbda1 in dact_process_file /home/ubuntu/fuzz3/dact-0.8.42/dact_common.c:581:17
    #2 0x4d4fc1 in main /home/ubuntu/fuzz3/dact-0.8.42/dact.c:689:8
    #3 0x7f322262a0b2 in __libc_start_main /build/glibc-YYA7BZ/glibc-2.31/csu/../csu/libc-start.c:308:16

SUMMARY: AddressSanitizer: heap-buffer-overflow (/home/ubuntu/fuzz3/dact-0.8.42/dact+0x4958ff) in __asan_memcpy
Shadow bytes around the buggy address:
  0x0fe6c3f17cb0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  0x0fe6c3f17cc0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  0x0fe6c3f17cd0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  0x0fe6c3f17ce0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  0x0fe6c3f17cf0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
=>0x0fe6c3f17d00: 00[03]fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
  0x0fe6c3f17d10: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
  0x0fe6c3f17d20: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
  0x0fe6c3f17d30: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
  0x0fe6c3f17d40: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
  0x0fe6c3f17d50: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
Shadow byte legend (one shadow byte represents 8 application bytes):
  Addressable:           00
  Partially addressable: 01 02 03 04 05 06 07
  Heap left redzone:       fa
  Freed heap region:       fd
  Stack left redzone:      f1
  Stack mid redzone:       f2
  Stack right redzone:     f3
  Stack after return:      f5
  Stack use after scope:   f8
  Global redzone:          f9
  Global init order:       f6
  Poisoned by user:        f7
  Container overflow:      fc
  Array cookie:            ac
  Intra object redzone:    bb
  ASan internal:           fe
  Left alloca redzone:     ca
  Right alloca redzone:    cb
  Shadow gap:              cc
==4163826==ABORTING
```

And where do I have to look in?

Do I have to look in main function of dact.c?

Comment: There are stack traces for the code that overran the buffer, and the code that allocated that buffer in the first place.  Do you know how to read stack traces?

Comment: @NateEldredge No. I'm trying to figure out how.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3988788/what-is-a-stack-trace-and-how-can-i-use-it-to-debug-my-application-errors may help; it's for Java but the concept is the same.